# Can jqplot barRenderer poitlabel date be shown with some angle, just like the X axis ticks?

Tags: jqplot

I have some data to be shown in a barRenderer.But there are some issue:the datas shown will Overlapping which will cause the datas can not be clearly read.Is there any way to deal with this?Or is it possible to show the data with some angle?Thanks a lot..

Comment: In the barRenderer, the pointLabel plugin is also used.The data all refers to the pointLabel data.

Comment: can you please share your code?